# Problems in Swift

Tags: swift

so I recently got in to Swift programming and I'm following Bloc's tutorial. So, when I make my Block class, I copied everything down to the letter, but still it says that "Type 'Block' does not conform to protocol Equatable", and I have no idea how to fix it. It also says that "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'", "Expected declaration", and "Operators are only allowed at global scope". Here's my code:

```
class Block: Hashable, Printable {

let color: BlockColor

var column: Int
var row: Int
var sprite: SKSpriteNode?

var spriteName: String {
    return color.spriteName
}

var hashValue: Int {
    return self.column ^ self.row
}

var description: String {
    return "\(color): [\(column), \(row)]"
}

init(column: Int, row: Int, color: BlockColor) {
    self.column = column
    self.row = row
    self.color = color
}

func == (lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool {
    return lhs.column == rhs.column && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.color.toRaw() == rhs.color.toRaw()
}
```

In addition, but not less important, what is the replacement for NSDate.date()? Because Bloc uses it, but when I use it, it says that it doesn't exist. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing closing brace in your code, just before `func ==`. That is to close the class declaration. Consequently, `func ==` must be in the global scope, outside of the class declaration.

```
class Block: Hashable, Printable {

    let color: BlockColor

    var column: Int
    var row: Int
    var sprite: SKSpriteNode?

    var spriteName: String {
        return color.spriteName
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.column ^ self.row
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(color): [\(column), \(row)]"
    }

    init(column: Int, row: Int, color: BlockColor) {
        self.column = column
        self.row = row
        self.color = color
    }
} // <-- this is missing

func == (lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool {
    return lhs.column == rhs.column && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.color.toRaw() == rhs.color.toRaw()
}
```

As for the date, if what you need is the current date and time, I think what you are looking for is the parameterless constructor:

```
NSDate()
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the replacement for NSDate.date() though?

Comment: Added at the end of the answer

Comment: Ok, that seems logical. Thanks!